# Is using an exception as a goto a pythonic approach?

Tags: python

I have a complex set of conditions, from which I would like to exit once one is met.

For that I would like to use a `try: / except:` structure around them to exit at the right time, which is similar to a `goto`. A convoluted example (using a `raise` to `break` from a `while`) would be:

```
class Minor(Exception):
    pass
class Major(Exception):
    pass

age = 15
while True:
    try:
        if age > 18:
            raise Major
        else:
            raise Minor
    except Major:
        print('major')
        break
    except Minor:
        print('minor')
        break
```

Is such use of exceptions pythonic? In other words: were exceptions intended to only catch what would have been a Traceback otherwise, or are do they have a general use like above?

EDIT: following comments, I would like to clarify that I am not looking at how to simplify this specific piece of code -- the real code is much more complex with nested loops and conditions. **The part I was interested in is whether there are reasons to specifically discourage the use of exceptions.**

Comment: No.  Why does it make sense to encapsulate the code you're raising to in an `except` block instead of just putting it in an `if` statement or a function call?

Comment: This does not look very pythonic to me. Will an if elif block with `break` statements not suffice?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: I assume that the 'no' in your comment means 'no, this is not pythonic'? As for your question: my real case is much more complex, with a set of fors and whiles, from which I want to escape once a set of criteria is met. Raising an exception was a solution I envisioned.

Comment: No. You create 2 empty classes (4 additional lines) for basically no reason. What if you have 5 different cases? Use `if` or `dict` if needed. Exceptions are not a control flow tool.

Comment: @WoJ My solution to that is usually to wrap it in a function that I can just `return` out of

Comment: In the provided example, the use of exceptions is obviously redundant. Could you give a more practical context?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: ah, that's a good idea too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, I added a clarification. The use case I have is more complicated - I gave the example to show the approach (exit from somewhere (in my real case: nested loops and conditions) by raising an exception)

Comment: Your example (even in a more complicated form) is not really pythonic indeed, but there are examples in Python of using exceptions as part of the control flow (iterators and `StopIteration` comes to mind). As for " reasons to specifically discourage the use of exceptions" in your case, I'd say, mostly, that there are very certainly ways to refactor it to something more readable and manageable instead.

Comment: Why is everyone answering in the comments here?  Just add an answer.

Comment: @DeepSpace: "exceptions are not a control flow tool" is what I was looking for (although a source would be great). What do you mean by "use `dict`"?

Comment: @wim: because the question is complicated and everybody is afraid of stepping in. Just kidding. Thanks for your answer which, while not explicitly addressing the point of exceptions, clearly makes a case for a `return` instead.

Comment: Rule #234: don't use exceptions for control flow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a pythonic approach.  The usual method of flow control used to escape from nested loops immediately is to put the logic into a function and use a `return` statement.

[PEP 3136](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/) was once proposed as a way to escape from nested loops using labeled break and continue statements:

> Labeled break and continue can improve the readability and flexibility of complex code which uses nested loops.

This PEP was rejected for Python 3.1.  Guido [wrote](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2007-July/008663.html):

> I'm rejecting it on the basis that code so complicated to
>   require this feature is very rare. In most cases there are existing
>   work-arounds that produce clean code, for example using 'return'.